# Integral restful JPA over Hibernate

Tags: json, hibernate, rest, jpa, jax-rs

It seems that [Eclispelink](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Release/2.4.0/JPA-RS/REST-API), [OpenJPA](http://openjpa.apache.org/2011/02/01/rest-on-openjpa.html) and [DataNucleus](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_0/rest/api.html) already provide integral restful JPA out of box.

How about `Hibernate`? I'm not looking for any scalfold framework that generates restful web services from entity classes, but integral JAX-RS and JPA over Hibernate, preferably with default JSON support.

Comment: I don't think hibernate provide REST support out of the box. You could check out [Spring Data Rest Project](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/rest). Hope this helps.